# How to integrate woocommerce software addon to a plugin

Tags: woocommerce

I have bought this woocommerce plugin Software Add-on and installed this on one my WP sites where I sell my premium plugins and themes. It works fine when a product is purchased and the order email contains a license key generated by this plugin.

My question is how to incorporate or integrate this plugin API to a plugin so that end users ( my product buyers) can enter the key in a form or so and get my plugin activated. I find one `test-script.php` and a `test-script-local.php`. But I do not find any doc or guidance as how I can incorporate this in my plugin. My plugin is simple - it has the plugin php file, one functions.php, one css and one js file.

Any idea or guidance will be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You need a plugin options page. Easy digital downloads actually has a very good example with the [docs for their software licensing](http://docs.easydigitaldownloads.com/article/380-activating-license-keys-in-wp-plugins-and-themes) plugin. Also see this [tutorial](http://ottopress.com/2009/wordpress-settings-api-tutorial/)

Comment: Thanks. The tutorial helps. Any idea how to do this for Woocommerce software add on? Sorry if my question sounds too naive.

Comment: It isn't naive so much as it is broad and more work than I am willing to do right now. You would need to integrate the WooCommerce software addon API example code into the EDD example. Otherwise the rest is the same. You could also borrow heavily from the [Woothemes Helper plugin](http://woodojo.s3.amazonaws.com/downloads/woothemes-updater/woothemes-updater.zip) that they use for their own products.